# Bash: how to turn list of unique no data values into variables that can be used?

Tags: bash, gdal

```
basepath=Desktop/DEM

dir=(ls -1 type -f)

cd $dir
for f in *.tif; do gdalinfo "$f" | grep -o 'NoData Value\=[-0-9]*' || echo "NoData Value=None"; done > test.txt
cat test.txt | sort | uniq > uniquenodata.txt #this is to find unique no data values in a directory 

nodatalist=$(cat uniquenodata.txt)
rightnodata=-9999
```

I have made the BASH script above to find out the different no data values in a directory.
My goal is to have separate folders that have only one type of no data value, I need to somehow create a for loop that will convert the list of unique no data values ($nodatalist) and check each tif's no data value and send it to the corresponding folder that has these no data values. I am very new to BASH and do not know how to turn a list of values into a variable that can be used in a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient approach is to move the files immediately. Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist.

```
for f in *.tif; do
    i=$(gdalinfo "$f" | grep -o 'NoData Value=[-0-9]*') && d=${i#NoData Value=} || d="None"
    mkdir -p "$d"
    mv "$f" "$d"/
done
```

As an aside, these lines look like a syntax error:

```
dir=(ls -1 type -f)
cd $dir
```

This will effectively `cd test` if you have a directory by this name. Maybe you actually mean `find -type f` but this obviously doesn't produce a directory (`-type f` specifically selects regular files which aren't directories).

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable indirection, a variable whose value is the name of another variable

```
for d in "${nodatalist[@]}"; do
    echo "${!d}"
done
```

As this example illustrates

```
declare -a a=("b" "c" "d");
b=1
c=2
d=3
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
   echo "name: $i, value: ${!i}"
done
```

Output:

```
name: b, value: 1
name: c, value: 2
name: d, value: 3
```